# using Cassandra 1.2.19 , Hector and cql3

Tags: cassandra, cql, hector

I am using cassandra 1.2 and Hector API.I have created the cql like,

```
    CREATE table FILES0 (
      FILE_NAME varchar PRIMARY KEY,
      CONTENT blob
    );

i.e, without using the COMPACT_STORAGE. 

Run the cql-files using test cases.
But: desc table files0;  resulted as, 

    CREATE TABLE "FILES0" ( "FILE_NAME" text PRIMARY KEY,"CONTENT" blob) WITH COMPACT STORAGE AND
      bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
      caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
    comment='' AND
      dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000.
```

how COMPACT_STORAGE added here???I found the same issue, when I ran the same cases in cassandra 1.2.15 ,1.2.19 and 2.0 versions.

Answer (score 1):

hector doesn't have support for creating cql3 tables.  To do that you would want to use a driver such as the [DataStax Java Driver](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver) which is designed to use cql3 and the c* native protocol.